# Sort DF bu multiple columns and custom order

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'label': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4], 
        'condition1': ['c','c','f','f','c','c','f','f','c','c','f','f','c','c','f','f'], 
        'condition2': ['c','f','c','f','c','f','c','f','c','f','c','f','c','f','c','f']})
```

I already used the following code to sort the df:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['label', 'condition1'], ascending=[True, True])
```

I would like to also sort 'condition2' so that it looks like this::

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'label': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4], 
        'condition1': ['c','c','f','f','c','c','f','f','c','c','f','f','c','c','f','f'], 
        'condition2': ['c','f','f','c','c','f','f','c','c','f','f','c','c','f','f','c']})
```

How can I achieve this? I have tried adding the condition2 into the sort_values but nothing happened.

Comment: what is the logic here?

Answer (score 0):

The logic remains to be clarified, but assuming that you want the first values of condition2 to match that of condition1, per group, you could compute a sorting Series based on the equality of the two columns:

```
tmp = df.sort_values(by=['label', 'condition1'], ascending=[True, True])

order = np.lexsort([tmp['condition2'].ne(tmp['condition1']), df['condition1'], df['label']])

out = df.iloc[order]
```

Output:

```
    label condition1 condition2
0       1          c          c
1       1          c          f
3       1          f          f
2       1          f          c
4       2          c          c
5       2          c          f
7       2          f          f
6       2          f          c
8       3          c          c
9       3          c          f
11      3          f          f
10      3          f          c
12      4          c          c
13      4          c          f
15      4          f          f
14      4          f          c
```